# Extract an object from an array of objects based on an id

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects that looks like this...

```
const arr = [
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": 36
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Laura",
    "age": 24
}
{
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Michael",
    "age": 28
}
{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Tim",
    "age": 54
}
]
```

I need javascript logic that can *extract an object based on an id* passed into it.

For example, if I pass in the number 4, it would return...

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Tim",
    "age": 54
}
```

since the id for that object matches the number 4. I *think* the solution involves .findIndex(), but I'm not able to figure out how to utilize that method into a solution.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You need `arr.find(item => item.id === 4)`

Comment: @ChrisG please post answers in the answers.

Comment: @James Are you kidding me?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this, but I think [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) is the most elegant.

```js
const arr = [
  { "id": 1, "name": "Bob", "age": 36 },
  { "id": 2, "name": "Laura", "age": 24 },
  { "id": 3, "name": "Michael", "age": 28 },
  { "id": 4, "name": "Tim", "age": 54 }
];

const extractObject = (id) => {
  return arr.filter(row => row.id === id).pop();
};

let laura = extractObject(2);

console.log(laura);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function findInSet(recordSet, id){
    return recordSet.find(element => element.id == id);
}
```